# CS50 pset3 find always returns true

Tags: search, find, helper, cs50

so I've been struggling with this for a fare old while now and need some help with bool functions. I'm stuck on the search part of helpers in pset3.

I know my selection sort function works, as I used printf to check the numbers are being sorted, and I tested find with a simple linear search to confirm it was working properly.

My code for the search function is as follows:

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)

{

// Set upper and lower limits for mid point calculation
int max = n - 1;
int min = 0;


while (min <= max)
{
    // Set the mid point of values as half the difference of the upper and lower limit.   
    int mid = (max - min)/ 2;

    // If the array position we look at for this itteration of mid is equal to the value, return true   
    if (value == values[mid])
    return true; 

    // If the mid value is less than our value, look at the right half (+1 as we dont need to look at the mid point again)   
    else if (value > values[mid])
    return min = mid + 1;

    // Same principle but for the left half of the array   
    else if (value < values [mid])
    return max = mid - 1;

}
return false;
```

}

As far as I can tell my logic is sound for the actual calculations. I've tried any number of different ways of returning false, such as "if (value < values[mid + 1] && value > values[mid -1]" to return false but to no avail so I've omitted them from the code here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't checked the logics of your code, but you can't set a function to return a bool but also use it to return numbers as in
    return min = mid + 1;
Or in
    return max = mid - 1;

Just set the function to return int instead and use 1 and 0 as true and false.

<s>Also, C doesn't have boolean types unless you are defining them in your code or importing stdbool.h</s>

Edit: just remembered that you can't change the signature of the function, so try creating a function of your own and then calling it inside the already defined search function.

Comment: You were spot on I was trying to return my new min and max, which was returned true for any value. Should have spotted that for all cases it was returning true hense the error was with my use of return. Thanks for the help.